# Combination of field search using PHP & MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am working on an assignment using PHP & MYSQL.

one of the tasks is to search on any combination of the fields. That includes Dropdown boxes populated from the Database. and Text fields.

t2ath contains

```
ID
SPORT
COUNTRY
GENDER
FIRSTNAME
LASTNAME
Image
```

I've been working on this code for a week to be able to search on any combination with no errors.

I am wondering if there is another more efficient way to do it.

```
$selectedSport = $_POST['sport']; $gender =$_POST['gender']; $fName =$_POST['fname']; $lName =$_POST['lname']; $country =$_POST['country'];
$sql_fName=""; $sql_lName=""; $sql_gender=""; $sql_sport=""; $sql_country="";
$checkFiled=False;
$where="";
$and="";
//
if ( $selectedSport=="showAll")
    {
        !isset($selectedSport);
    }
else
    {
        if (isset($selectedSport)) 
            { 
                if ($checkFiled==True)
                    {

                        $sql_sport = " AND t2ath.sport = '$selectedSport'" ; 

                    }
                else
                    {
                        $sql_sport = " t2ath.sport = '$selectedSport' " ; 
                        $checkFiled=True;   
                    } 
            }
        else {
            $sql_sport = "";  
        }
    }

//
if ( $country =="showAll")
    {
        !isset($country);
    }
else
    {
        if (isset($country)) 
            { 
                if ($checkFiled ==True)
                    {

                        $sql_country = " AND t2ath.country = '$country'" ; 

                    }
                else
                    {
                        $sql_country = " t2ath.country = '$country' " ; 
                        $checkFiled=True;
                    } 
            }
        else {
            $sql_country = "";  
        }
    }
//
if ( $gender=="Gender")
    {
        !isset($gender);
    }
else
    {
        if (isset($gender)) 
            { 
                if ($checkFiled ==True)
                    {

                        $sql_gender = " AND t2ath.gender = '$gender'" ; 

                    }
                else
                    {
                        $sql_gender = " t2ath.gender = '$gender' " ; 
                        $checkFiled=True;
                    } 
            }
        else {
            $sql_gender = "";  
        }
    }
//
if ($fName =="")
    {
        !isset($fName);
    }
else
    {
        if (isset($fName)) 
            { 
                if ($checkFiled==True)
                    {

                        $sql_fName = " AND t2ath.firstName = '$fName'" ; 
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $sql_fName = " t2ath.firstName = '$fName' " ; 
                        $checkFiled=True;   
                    } 
            }
        else {
            $sql_fName = "";  
        }
    }
//
if ($lName =="")
    {
        !isset($lName);
    }
else
    {
        if (isset($lName)) 
            { 
                if ($checkFiled==True)
                    {

                        $sql_lName = " AND t2ath.lastName = '$lName' " ; 

                    } 
                else
                    {
                        $sql_lName = " t2ath.lastName = '$lName' " ; 
                        $checkFiled=True;
                    }
            }
        else
            {
                $sql_lName = "";  
            }
    }

if ($checkFiled == True)
    $where=" where ";

$selectString = "SELECT t2ath.lastName,t2ath.firstName,t2ath.image,t2ath.sport,t2ath.gender,t2ath.country,t2country.flag FROM t2ath LEFT JOIN t2country
                 ON t2ath.country = t2country.name $where  $sql_sport   $sql_country $sql_gender $sql_fName $sql_lName  ";
$result = mysql_query($selectString);
```

Comment: If you are just learning now, STOP using the deprecated mysql extension and use the mysqli (http://us1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension. It supports, among other things, prepared statements, which would make your code much more manageable. Also the code `!isset($lName);` does not unset the variable, it returns whether the variable is already set. To unset a variable, use `unset($lName);`

Comment: Why do you need to unset those variables at all? You never refer to them outside the `if` blocks.

Comment: @Anthony Actually, dynamically generated SQL like this is _harder_ to do with mysqli prepared statements, because it's difficult to call `mysqli_stmt_bind_params` with a dynamic set of parameters. This type of thing is much easier in PDO, since you can use an array of parameters.

Comment: The parameters don't need to be dynamic. It's a tad convoluted, but you since there are a finite set of fields and values to compare them to, in the case of the value being 'All', the input could be modified to simply leave those blank (have the dropdown show 'All' and the value be empty), and then have the query check for `WHERE (sport = $sport OR $sport = '')` which will return all rows when the value is blank and the matches when set.  And you should not discourage anyone from using something other than the mysql api. I don't care if they switch to PDO or MYSQLI, the goal is to switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of all those conditionals about whether to add `AND` when concatenating to the query, use an array and `implode`.

```
$fields = array('sport' => 'sport',
                'gender' => 'gender', 
                'fname' => 'firstName',
                'lname' => 'lastName',
                'country' => 'country');
$wheres = array();
foreach ($fields as $postfield => $dbfield) {
    if ($_POST[$postfield] != 'showAll') {
        $wheres[] = "$dbfield = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$postfield]) . "'";
    }
}
$selectString = "SELECT t2ath.lastName, t2ath.firstName, t2ath.image, t2ath.sport, t2ath.gender, t2ath.country, t2country.flag 
                 FROM t2ath LEFT JOIN t2country
                 ON t2ath.country = t2country.name";
if (count($wheres) > 0) {
    $selectString .= " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $wheres);
}
$result = mysql_query($selectString);
```

To see how to do it similarly using PDO prepared statements, see my answer here: [What code approach would let users apply three optional variables in PHP/MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197034/3-user-selected-variable-database-using-php-mysql-methodology/21197328#21197328)

Answer (score 0):

Why not evaluate your string with each column (this is a guide only, I'm not building your PHP code there:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table
WHERE 
  (ID = $id OR $id = 'showAll')
  AND (SPORT = $sport OR $sport = 'showAll')
  AND (COUNTRY = $country OR $country = 'showAll')
  AND (GENDER = $gender OR $gender = 'showAll')
  AND (FIRSTNAME = $firstname OR $firstname = 'showAll')
```

Just need to make sure you NVL the variables to an appropriate value (whether it be int or string)

Comment: Also, you're missing quotes around all the variables.

Comment: Feel free to edit as you see fit - it's more a push in the right direction than giving him code for his homework

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in the past where I checked the value from different fields and then added them to a series of arrays.  I created an array for select, from, where, order.  You can do similar for other sets like group or limit.  Then I ran 'array_unique', imploded them and put them into the SQL string.

```
$array_select = array('users.Id'); // SET SOME DEFAULTS SO THE QUERY WILL ALWAYS RUN
$array_from = array('users');
$array_where = array();
$array_order = array();

if (isset($first_name)) {
    $array_select[] = 'First_Name';
    $array_from[] = 'users';
}

if (isset($city)) {
    $array_select[] = 'City';
    $array_from[] = 'user_contact';
    $array_where[] = 'users.Id = user_contact.City';
}

if ($array_select) {
    $array_select = array_unique($array_select);
    $string_select = implode(', ', $array_select);
}
if ($array_where) {
    $array_where = array_unique($array_where);
    $string_where = 'WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $array_where);
}
// REPEAT FOR OTHERS ...



// BUILD THE QUERY OUT
$sql = 'SELECT '.$string_select.' FROM '.$string_from.' '.$string_where.' ...
```